# Attaching .txt files in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am developing a desktop application in VB.NET 2005. I have a requirement whereby a user need to select a .txt file from his machine (client) and after clicking the save button, i need this file to be saved in the server into a specific folder.

Similarly, i should be able to retrieve the file as well.

Please help on this requirement.

Comment: And what is (running on) 'the Server' ?

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I do it.
The things you need is a folder named "Uploads".
All the rest is done automaticaly.

First when a user open's the page where the uploading is done on a Page_Load I do the following to make sure the folder for the authenticated user is created.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If My.User.IsAuthenticated Then
        Try
            If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
                Select Case My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists (Server.MapPath ("~/Uploads"))
                    Case False
                        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory (Server.MapPath ("~/Uploads"))
                End Select
                Select Case My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists (Server.MapPath ("~/Uploads/" & My.User.Name))
                    Case False
                        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory (Server.MapPath ("~/Uploads/" & My.User.Name))
                End Select
                ListMyFiles()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
         'Some code for catching exceptions
        End Try
    Else
        Response.Redirect ("YOUR LOGIN PAGE")
    End If

End Sub
```

Then on the page I already added a ASP:FileUpload control.
On the Click eveent of this control I add this code

```
 Try
        Select Case FileUpload1.HasFile
            Case True
                Dim fname = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName
                SaveFile(FileUpload1.PostedFile)
                ListMyFiles()
            Case False
                Fupload.Text = "Please select a file for uploading!"
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
     'Some code for catching exceptions
    End Try
```

The SaveFile function has the following code

```
 Sub SaveFile (ByVal file As HttpPostedFile)
    Try
        Dim _
            filext = _
                Split (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName, ".") ( _
                                                              Split (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName, ".").Length - _
                                                              1)
        Select Case filext
            Case "txt"
                Dim foldername = "~/Uploads/" & My.User.Name
                Dim filename = foldername & "/Uploaded_" & FileUpload1.FileName
                Dim savePath As String = "~/Uploads/" & My.User.Name
                Dim pathToSave As String = Server.MapPath (filename)
                Select Case IO.File.Exists (pathToSave)
                    Case False
                        FileUpload1.SaveAs (pathToSave)
                        Dim uploadedFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText ((pathToSave))
                        uploadedFile = uploadedFile
                        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText (pathToSave, uploadedFile, False)
                        Dim msg As String = "Your file was uploaded successfully."
                        Fupload.Text = msg

                    Case True
                        Dim _
                            msg As String = _
                                "You have already uploaded this file. Please delete the file from server first and then try to upload it again."
                        Fupload.Text = msg

                End Select
            Case Else
                Dim _
                    msg As String = "The file type '" & filext & _
                                    "' you are trying to upload is not allowed. You can only upload '.txt' files."
                Fupload.Text = msg

        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Some code for catching exceptions
    End Try


End Sub
```

and the ListMyFiles functions has the following code.

```
 Protected Sub ListMyFiles()
    Try
        Dim foldername = "~/Uploads/" & My.User.Name

        Dim files As New List(Of MyFiles)
        For Each s As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles (Server.MapPath (foldername) & "\")
            Dim f As New MyFiles
            f.Filename = Split (s, "\") (Split (s, "\").Length - 1)
            f.CompletePath = s
            f.FileSize = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo (s).Length
            files.Add (f)
        Next
        ListFiles.DataSource = files
        ListFiles.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Some code for catching exceptions
    End Try

End Sub
```

Hope I solved your problem.
I know that you could tweak the code but this had done the job for me.
There is another way you can use by storing the files as binary on you database but I choose to do it this way since it's simpler.

Comment: I know that the `My`-Namespace has it's beauties, but I prefer to import the `System.IO`-Namespace and use `File`, `Directory` and `Path` directly, saves a whole lot of typing.

Comment: Also, you might want to refrain from using the `Microsoft.VisualBasic`-Namespace, it's there for compatibility reasons, but imho defies the whole meaning of VB.NET being an OO-Language. F.e., use `"MyString".Split("."c)` instead. You mgiht also want to use `[System.IO.]Path.Combine(String, String)` for concatenating paths.

Comment: Also I supossed this app is an web app.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would probably be to set up a fileshare on the server and then the client app just saves the text file to that shared directory. Or set up a FTP server on the server and send it over via that (or some other similar technology, DAV etc, might be worth asking around on Superuser.com about this since it wouldn't really be a programming question).

Otherwise you could write some kind of webservice or TCP/IP server to run on the server and accept incoming connections from the client and transfer the file via that. But that sounds a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

As ho1 mentions, a good option would be to send the text file over FTP. [Here is a useful link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/FtpClient.aspx?fid=225949&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=201) for FTP'ing from inside your application.